# How to handle Spring transactions inside coroutines?

Tags: spring, kotlin, transactions, kotlinx.coroutines

It is known that Spring transactions are tied to threads: there are thread locals specific for an ongoing transaction. And transactions know nothing about coroutine context. So what if I would like to call a @Transactional method from inside a coroutine: is it safe?

Imagine we have a method inside JobProcessor bean processing a job list. Each job is processed inside async{}. And I would like to update DB after every successful or failed processing using @Transactional methods of bean JobService.

```
class JobProcessor {
    fun process(jobs: List<MyJob>) =
        jobs.map { job ->
            async {
                try {
                    ....//processing
                    jobService.success(job)
                } catch (t: Throwable) {
                    jobService.failure(job)
                }
        }
} 

class JobService {
    @Transactional
    fun success(job: MyJob) {...}

    @Transactional
    fun failure(job: MyJob) {...}
}
```

Comment: Does `process` have a transactional context already?

Comment: No, process does not have transactional context

Answer (score 1):

First, please keep in mind that annotating bean methods with `@Transactional` will not suffice - make sure you enabled declarative transaction handling, e.g. by adding `@EnableTransactionManagement` to a `@Configuration` class or by using    `<tx-annotation-driven />` in XML config.

Regarding your question: There will only be a transactional context while executing Spring bean methods annotated with `@Transactional` when they are being invoked from a Spring bean outside of their containing class! Declarative transactions in Spring rely on AOP proxy classes being created for the `@Transactional` annotated classes by Spring. At runtime if a Spring bean A calls a `@Transactional` method on a Spring bean B, the call will be intercepted by an AOP proxy that transparently spawns a transaction, calls the original method of Spring bean B and commits or rollbacks this transaction afterwards.

***Remember: Only external method calls that come in through the proxy will be intercepted – any self-invocation calls, as in your example this.process() calling `@Transactional` methods `this.success()` or `this.failure()` will not start any transaction – even if the method is annotated with `@Transactional`.***

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have updated the code snippet accordingly. And @EnableTransactionManagement is present. So the initial question remains.